# C# Read Simple Json String

Tags: c#, json, parsing

some ideas how to read this simple JSON String to a List?

```
["amazon.de","ebay.de","fischevortische.de","homefuerst.de"]
```

i just wanna add every item to my List blackList

Comment: Please read our [Ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

1. Quick but only for a list of string.

   ```
   string jsonText = "[\"amazon.de\",\"ebay.de\",\"fischevortische.de\",\"homefuerst.de\"]";
   char[] separators = new char[] {'[', ']', ',', '"'};
   string[] result1 = jsonText.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   ```
2. Using JSON library ([included in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx))

   ```
   string jsonText = "[\"amazon.de\",\"ebay.de\",\"fischevortische.de\",\"homefuerst.de\"]";
   var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
   var result2 = jss.Deserialize<string[]>(jsonText);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
string json = "[\"amazon.de\",\"ebay.de\",\"fischevortische.de\",\"homefuerst.de\"]";
List<string> parsed = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray>(json).Values<string>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>();
```

Comment: please describe more..